# Can't launch jupyter notebook or spyder from anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, conda

this is my first time posting on this forum.

Recently, I update my anaconda navigator to version 2.0.1. After doing so, I can't launch or update any application (i.e. spyder, jupyter notebook) through the anaconda navigator window. I can do so using the anaconda prompt, but, strangely, I can't do it in the windows.

For your information, I update the navigator with the following command:

```
conda deactivate
```

and then

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

My conda version is 4.10.1.

Thank you for reading till here. I appreciate any comments on this issue.

Comment: are you seeing any errors? or any clue that can help. when you click notebook from the window, it opens a command prompt window, did you saw any error there?

Comment: @simpleApp Thanks for your reply. No, when I click notebook from the navigator window, I can see the loading status in the right bottom of the window, but after that, nothing happens. I tried updating my jupyter notebook from the window yesterday, and nothing happens too. However, I can still launch or update jupyter notebook through the anaconda command prompt via the start menu.